# schroot: pass a command to be executed as if it’s in a shell

Tags: linux, unix, chroot

i want to do something like:

```
schroot -c name -u root "export A=3 && export B=4"
```

but I get the error:

```
Failed to execute “export”: No such file or directory
```

In other words, I want to be able to programmatically execute shell commands inside the [schroot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/schroot.1.html) environment. What is the right way to get this behavior?

Comment: I think maybe this question belong on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend:

```
schroot -c name -u root sh -c "export A=3 && export B=4"
```

or better:

```
schroot -c name -u root -- sh -c "export A=3 && export B=4"
```

This runs the shell with the '-c' option telling it (the shell) to read the following argument as the command (script) to be executed.  The same technique works with other analogous commands: 'su', 'nohup', ...

The `--` option terminates the arguments to `schroot` and ensures that any options on the rest of the command line are passed to and interpreted by the shell, not by `schroot`.  This was suggested by [SR_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706859/sr) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074512/schroot-pass-a-command-to-be-executed-as-if-it-s-in-a-shell/3074544?noredirect=1#comment98565060_3074544), and the man page for `schroot` also suggests it should be used too (search for 'Separator').  The [GNU `getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) function by default permutes arguments, which is not wanted here.  The `--` prevents it from permuting the arguments after the `--`.

Comment: Using `--` prevents the second `-c` option to be interpreted as another `schroot` option. `schroot -c name -u root -- sh -c "export A=3 && export B=4"`

Comment: @SR_ only that worked here, it could be an answer and not just a comment !

Answer (score 4):

```
schroot -c name -u root -- export A=3 && export B=4
```

Ensuring that /etc/schroot/schroot.conf has

```
run-exec-scripts=true
run-setup-scripts=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
schroot -c name -u root "/bin/bash -c 'export A=3; export B=4'"
```

but this is the first time i've heard of schroot.  And the exports look like they're useless...even running the double-quoted stuff directly from the command line, it seems the child shell doesn't want to affect the parent's environment.

Comment: I think the quoting would work out better for more complex commands if you did `schroot -c name -u root /bin/bash -c 'export A=3; export B=4'` instead.

Comment: Possibly.  But like i said, i've never seen schroot before.  I wasn't sure whether the command had to be one string or what.